# How to center this button even though it's already centered in Computer resolution

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

[Mobile Resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3R3n.png)

So I'm using bootstrap and managed to center it but when I changed my resoluton/make it smaller the button wrapped and moved to the right a bit, Can anyone tell me what did I do wrong with it?

```
--HTML--
<div class="d-grid gap-2 col-2 mx-auto text-center">
       <button id="Get" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg" type="button">Newest Upload</button> </div>

--CSS--
#Get {
    border-width: 4px;
    font-family: Lexend;
}
```

I tried to center it and it worked on bigger resolution but moved to the left when it's on mobile resolution

Answer (score -1):

You can try adding relative positioning `position: relative` to the parent `<div>`, and then add absolute positioning `position: absolute` to the button, along with `left: 50%; top: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`.

This way, the position of the button will be independent of the resolution and screen size.Hope to be able to solve your problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).